# Not able to insert edited data from Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2013, insert

Using GridView I am trying to insert all the records, including the edited column into the database, by clicking the submit button. However, it is always inserting the initial data which was fetched from the database after the page load.

I want user to edit the column 'id', and after clicking on submit button, all the records should be inserted into a table. With the current code, the insertion is happening, however in id column, I always get "MG_US-FCWI1.05.30" and "MG_US-FCWI1.05.10" in DB. But I want "MG_US-FCWI1" and "MG_US-FCW" to be inserted. I am using VS2013.

[image: When the GridView is populating]

[image: After edit and expected entry in DB]

Code used -

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="column_name" HeaderText ="Material Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="part number" HeaderText ="Material Number" />                    
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtedit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GL_account" HeaderText ="GL Account" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit_Data" Height="21px" style="margin-left: 260px; margin-top: 14px;" />
        
        
        
    protected void Submit_Data(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {                      
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(getConn());
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into test ([Sales Order Id],[input data],Material_Name,[Part Number],id,GL_Account) values  (" + sales_order_id + "," + input_id + ",'" + row.Cells[0].Text + "','" + row.Cells[1].Text + "','" + ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].FindControl("txtedit")).Text + "','" + row.Cells[3].Text + "')", con);
                    con.Open();
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
    }
```

Comment: Hum, why is textbox set as readonly? I mean, it should not matter, but I would remove that read only tag

Comment: That's correct. It can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a REALLY good example as to why you don't want to concatenate that long string (reduces SQL injection issues - but ALSO allows for easier to read and easier to write code).

it beyond hard to read, and thus cleaning this up?

Then the error(s) in the code become clear.

You have this:

```
((TextBox)row.Cells[2].FindControl("txtedit")).Text
```

but, it should be this:

```
((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtedit")).Text
```

Lesson: Make your code readable, and you find your bugs and issue a lot faster.

Say something like this:

```
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into test " +
                "([Sales Order Id],[input data],Material_Name,[Part Number],id,GL_Account)" +
                "(@SalesID,@InputData,@MatName,@PartNum,@id,@GLAccount)",
                new SqlConnection(getConn()));

            com.Connection.Open();
            com.Parameters.Add("@SalesID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sales_order_id;
            com.Parameters.Add("@InputData", SqlDbType.Int).Value = input_id;
            com.Parameters.Add("@MatName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = row.Cells[0].Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@PartNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[1].Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@GlAccount", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtedit")).Text;

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            com.Connection.Close();

        }
```

I don't think you need a Convert.ToInt32() around the int values.

But, by just re-writing the code as readable, then the findcontrol error was easy to spot. Also, note how we don't have to guess if we need extra quotes around strings, or not for numbers - so we strong casting here, and that also works better.

Now above is air code, but after I had typed the first parameter, then I started hitting ctr-d to duplicate the line - so the amount of typing I had to do was actually quite small - between intellisense and <kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd>, then typing was reduced, but the code is not only easier to read, but we could for example add another row/parameter set over time, and again modifying this code would be less taxed on your carbon based computer (your brain) as opposed to the computer based silicon brain.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It did simply the code. However it still didn't resolve my issue. The edited text is still not being written in the DB.

Comment: and you removed the readonly tag? - that would prevent edits.  So you looking to insert a new row - not edit existing rows? Yes, what you have should work.

Comment: No, I did not remove the readonly tag. I just replicated your C# code. Still, the issue remains same. I can edit the text box in GridView, but not able to write that edited text in DB.

Comment: Well, is a error occurring, or are no values being inserted? Is the row count of the table increasing after the code runs? add a using "using System.Diagnostics;" and add a few debug.writeline commands to see what the value are? I mean, the insert command has to fail or at the very least insert a row into the table with some blank values. Put a button on that form, and write some hard code to insert a test row, does that work?

Comment: There is no error. I am pre populating the gridview with data as shown in first image. I am making the id column editable, so that users can edit. After editing, the second image's value I want to insert in DB. However, it always insert the first image's value after clicking the submit button.

Comment: I found the issue. I missed to add if (!IsPostBack) in Page_load function which was causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you for sharing what the issue was. Yes, load of controls, grids, and combo, etc? Always adopt a desing in which these are loaded only is the ispostback = false. Well done on your part!!!